# Converting JSON in classes

Tags: c#, json, class, deserialization

I need some help to convert this kind of JSON object in to c# classes so than I can Deserialize it

Here how it looks:

```
{  
   "Result":{  
      "test_one":"test",
      "test_two":"test",
      "main":[  
         {  
            "@attributes":{  
               "ID":"1",
               "Name":"test1"
            }
         },
        {  
            "@attributes":{  
               "ID":"2",
               "Name":"test2"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the newtonsoft nuget package, it will handle everything for you.  Here is the link to the documentation. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: This has been asked before. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object

Comment: Those two links explain on simple json object this one is more complex that is why I am confised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add new class
2. Copy your json
3. Visual Studio Menu > Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes

Comment: Thanks very useful to know I will accept this when available

Answer (score 0):

You could use an online converter :)
This one will work for your json: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)