# C# Generate json class with dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I wanted to ask how I can make a json class from the json file using **dictionary**.
Unfortunately I do not know how the class has to look. The Copy & Paste generators do not help. And how I can use it after that is the deserialization.

Thank you in advance

---

```
{
  "Keywordmask": "Packingtable",
  "Keywords": {
    "Itemnumber": "SA4F5ASD",
    "Productname": "DA51SAD",
    "Customerorder": "44SAD",
    "Productionorder": "454DSA54-002",
    "Serialnumber": "C3H3",
    "Customernumber": "30604",
    "Customer": "Horst",
    "Endcustomer": "Magret",
    "Repair": "0",
    "Repair Itemnumber": "",
    "Comment": "",
    "Patternpicture": "1",
    "Created On": "12.04.2017 11:42:04"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where you'd want a dictionary there. It looks like it should just be a class with one string property and one property of another type. (Note that it would be easier for many readers to get context if you translated the JSON into English. It only has to be *representative* of your real data.)

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Keywordmask
{
    public string Keywordmask { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Keywords{ get; set; }
}
```

Change class name to whatever is suitable

Then to convert the JSON to C# try one of the following methods

[How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Comment: Where's the dictionary the OP asked for?

Comment: These are the generators that are also available in the VS. They bring nothing to me.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
And how do I use them?

Comment: Thanks again. But I will unfortunately not get smarter out of it.

Comment: Well the JSON to CSharp generators only provide the properties you give where as you wanted to a dictionary to allow any keywords so that is how I came to this answer

Comment: I mean, as I use it later to dezeralize the json file

Comment: If you look at the JSON you provided it is just a data model. It is like an instance of a C# class. It has properties with values.

Comment: If you found this answer to be correct could you press the tick next to the answer, thanks