# C# Converting JSON objects to array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object

I got below data as JSON Objects:

```
{"Data1":
    {"id":1,
     "last":"0.00000045"},
"Data2":
    {"id":2,
     "last": "0.02351880"}}
```

What is the best way in c# to convert it to below JSON Array:

```
[{"name":"Data1",
     "id":1,
     "last":"0.00000045"},
    {"name":"Data2",
     "id":2,
     "last": "0.02351880"}]
```

Thanks in advance,

iziz1

Comment: You can find many ways in this link or related searchs. [Json Converstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following codes;

Firstly, create model classes for deserialization

```
public class Data
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}

public class DataWithKey
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize the original Json as `Dictionary<string, Data>` and convert to desired list; (Requires [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/))

```
var dataAsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(json).Select(x => new DataWithKey
{
    name = x.Key,
    id = x.Value.id,
    last = x.Value.last
}).ToList();
var convertedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataAsList); //Desired json
```

**Output:**

```
[
   {
      "name":"Data1",
      "id":1,
      "last":"0.00000045"
   },
   {
      "name":"Data2",
      "id":2,
      "last":"0.02351880"
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer and help. It is working perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked.

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data) class to serialize and deserialize json data.