# JSON string to C# class object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

How to deserialize a `JSON` to `POCO` based on the fact that the `JSON` is never the same. This includes the number of attribute, the type of attribute etc.

Basically I want to take in a variety of JSON and convert it to C# class object. I know it can be done, but I just have no idea how.

For clarity, I currently have this, where the url is dynamic.

```
var json = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

How could I retrieve an object from this `JSON`?

Comment: Deserialize to `dynamic`.

Comment: See [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) for potential solutions.

Comment: Classes are determined on compile-time and not on run-time. The best you can do is to use `dynamic`.

Comment: oh yes finally.. thanks