# Convert JSON to C# POCO

Tags: c#, json

I have below JSON data

```
{
   "appDesc": {
                "description": "App description.",
                "message": "Create and edit presentations "
              },
   "appName": {
                "description": "App name.",
                "message": "Slides"
              }
}
```

I want to Deserialize into `C#` class object. I am using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>()` to achieve this functionality. But some how it is not working.

```
 string JsonData= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(msgJSONpath);

 var moreInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<appName>(msg)



internal class appName
{
    public string message { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

So **moreInfo** object will have 2 properties in message and description.

Comment: show your class you want to de-serialize into

Comment: internal class appName
    {
        public string message { get; set; }

        public string description { get; set; }
    }

Comment: edit your question and add your relevant code

Comment: Senario is, when I read a .json file which is having above data, I need to convert them into objects. Something like I have mentioned above.

Comment: Add your code which you have tried

Comment: Compile-able code please.

Comment: The type should be Dictionary<string, appName>

Comment: `msg` does not eixst in the current context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JObject defines method Parse for this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

or try for a typed object try:

```
Foo json  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need 2 C# classes since the properties of appName and appDesc are exactly the same.

1. To store appname

   ```
   public class appName {
     public string description { get; set; }
     public string message { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. A class to have both above classes as properties

   ```
   public class appResult {
     public appName appDesc { get; set; }
     public appName appName { get; set; }

     public appResult() {
       appDesc = new appName();
       appName = new appName();
     }
   }
   }
   ```
3. desirialize the json

   ```
   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<appResult>(msg);
   ```
4. Once you have the result object you can get your `appName`

   ```
   var appName = result.appName;
   ```

Comment: `appName` and `appDesc` are the same. There's no reason to use separate classes for them

Comment: @BackSlash i just saw it now, why it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

First ,you need to create some classes based on your JSON , if you,re using visual studio you can copy the JSON string to your clipboard and than go to

Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes

otherwise you can use [This Online Tool](http://json2csharp.com/)

after that your code should be something like this :

```
     string JsonData= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(msgJSONpath);

     var moreInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(msg);
```

**Generated Classes Based On Your JSON** :

```
    public class AppDesc
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class AppName
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public AppDesc appDesc { get; set; }
    public AppName appName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This would be a good answer if you pasted the generated classes as well