# Reading the data received via the MarkEmbling library for postcodes.io

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to read the data to a string from postcodes.io using the MarkEmbling library, I can't seem to output the data to a readable string.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho57l.jpg

I want to output the data to a textbox which shows the town, county and region but it just shows the data as the image above. (I'm using the textbox for testing) also this is my first program.

This is just a simple front end desktop application for postcodes.io using the MarkEmbling library.

```
var data = textBox1.Text;
string myData = data.ToString();

var client = new PostcodesIOClient();
var result = client.Lookup(myData);

string myResult = result.ToString();

MessageBox.Show(myResult);
```

Comment: Lookup returns a PostCodeResult Object, which is already parsed: https://github.com/markembling/MarkEmbling.PostcodesIO/blob/d5814a4a3a9b195c804c9701ef7585d094f70685/MarkEmbling.PostcodesIO/Results/PostcodeResult.cs

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed that shouldn't have been lazy and actually looked more into the documentation.

Comment: The question is quit unclear. You are getting a Json from postcodes.io. But what you expect is unclear. Display the Json string indented? Deseriliaze the Json into an object in order to use the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Comment: @OmniCodec If your question got answered, close this question by selecting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The return of Lookup is of type "PostcodeResult", which is the already processed (or as MarkEmbling uses in the library: "executed") result.

You can check the source code to see the available properties: https://github.com/markembling/MarkEmbling.PostcodesIO/blob/d5814a4a3a9b195c804c9701ef7585d094f70685/MarkEmbling.PostcodesIO/Results/PostcodeResult.cs

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to read the data from the library with the following example.

```
var result = client.Lookup(myData);

string myResult = result.AdminCounty + "\n" + result.AdminDistrict + "\n" + result.Region.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert object to string by `JavaScriptSerializer` and show

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result);
MessageBox.Show(json );
```