# How can I get data from this JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

The JSON data is:

```
{\"data\": [
  [\"f45dc1c8-b5ef-29ad-c12bc9731ddc1b59\", \"10002800\"],
  [\"1bcf618d-87c3-3542-61abbee73e09a29e\", \"10040646\"],
  ["c523aa86-2040-2eeb-844c16d61cad94ec", "10009514, 32295968"],
  ["1bcf618d-87c3-3542-61abbee73e09a29e", "10040646"],
  ....
]}
```

How can I get

```
"f45dc1c8-b5ef-29ad-c12bc9731ddc1b59",
"1bcf618d-87c3-3542-61abbee73e09a29e",
"c523aa86-2040-2eeb-844c16d61cad94ec",
....
```

by C#?

Comment: It is customary for you to do some research and try it yourself, then ask a specific question about a problem. Please [see how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: just search how to covert json to dictionary in C# in your search engine

Comment: Is that your actual JSON?  I'm confused because some of the values have quotes preceded by blackslashes while others do not.  As it stands, it is not valid JSON.

Comment: I'm not sure but I got it from partner API. I cannot parse data

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Here is an example:

```
string json = @"{ ""key1"":""value1"",
                 ""key2"":""value2""}";

var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Also, [see this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246724/159072).