# How to do dynamic object mapping in C#

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to create a dynamic JSON response based on master model class in C#.

**GIVEN**

```
    public class Person
    {
       public string Firstname {get; set;}
       public string Lastname {get; set;}
       public string Gender {get; set;}
    }
    var personObj = new Person {Firstname = "Foo", Lastname = "Bar", Gender = "M"};
    var responseJsonTemplate1 = "{\"Firstname\":\"\",\"Gender\":\"\"}";
    var responseJsonTemplate2 = "{\"Firstname\":\"\",\"Lastname\":\"\"}";
```

**EXPECTATION**

```
   var responseJson1 = "{\"Firstname\":\"Foo\",\"Gender\":\"Male\"}";
   var responseJson2 = "{\"Firstname\":\"Foo\",\"Lastname\":\"Bar\"}";
```

I want to generate JSON response from the **personObj** based on the template JSON string.

Is there any library to do such type of mapping?

**Note:**

1. The template JSON will always follow the structure of Person class
2. Since the response JSON will be dynamic and with any combinations of properties, we can't create a concrete class for each response JSON. It has to be dynamically generated.

Comment: _"Since the response JSON will be dynamic and with any combinations of properties"_ how do they get selected?

Comment: try NewtonSoft.JSON

Comment: You're asking about dynamic serialization, *not* dynamic mapping. That's one problem. The other is finding out the property names contained in those JSON strings. Any JSON parser could handle this, as those JSON strings are essentially dictionaries. Why do that though? Why not pass the property names as an array? Are you trying to implement some specific protocol? Perhaps it's already implemented

Comment: The final response JSON should be formed based on the properties defined in the template JSON and the template JSON can have any combinations of properties but the property path will be consistent wrt original personObj

Comment: So, basically I am looking for a generic logic to fill in the values of properties in the template JSON from the personObj dynamically. I can do this easily with AutoMapper if I create concrete classes for each template but that is what I do not want to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Answer (score -1):

A good way to use JSON in C# is with [JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json)

[Quick Starts & API Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) from  [JSON.NET - Official site](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) help you work with it.

```
    var personObj = new Person { Firstname = "Foo", Lastname = "Bar", Gender = "M" };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personObj);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
    //{"Firstname":"Foo","Lastname":"Bar","Gender":"M"}

    //and if you want the aother way :

    string jsonS = @"{'Firstname': 'Foo','Lastname':'Bar','Gender':'M'}";
    Person personObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonS);
```

Comment: if that didn't help tell me why