# How to convert Prediction.Entities returned from LUISRuntimeClient in a strongly typed class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm testing a Luis app using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime package in VS2019.
I getting a list of entities from the prediction but it's a json with many properties. I want to code with it in elengant way, without dealing with json. Is there some class that i can convert the entity into it and work with?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't class for us to convert the json entity into it, we need to parse the json by ourself. We can create a class which its attributes match the entity json properties, and then convert the json to the class object.

It's not difficult to parse the json to class, below is a sample for your reference:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jUser = jObject["user"];
        name = (string) jUser["name"];
        teamname = (string) jUser["teamname"];
        email = (string) jUser["email"];
        players = jUser["players"].ToArray();
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string teamname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Array players { get; set; }
}

// Use
private void Run()
{
    string json = @"{""user"":{""name"":""asdf"",""teamname"":""b"",""email"":""c"",""players"":[""1"",""2""]}}";
    User user = new User(json);

    Console.WriteLine("Name : " + user.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Teamname : " + user.teamname);
    Console.WriteLine("Email : " + user.email);
    Console.WriteLine("Players:");

    foreach (var player in user.players)
        Console.WriteLine(player);
 }
```

And there are many other [solutions/samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object) to convert the json.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some class that i can convert the entity into it and work
> with?

Andrew, I have successfully deserialized a LUIS v2 REST endpoint JSON response into `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models.LuisResult` from the [Microsoft.Bot.Builder v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/3.30.0) package (note could not find a compatible type in the latest v4 package), which is far more elegant than working with the raw JSON.

[image]