# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'items', line 1, position 43

Tags: c#, json

Code im trying:

```
        public static void Values() {
            using (WebClient wb = new WebClient()) {
                wb.Headers["user-agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36";
                Dictionary<string, string> dictObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(wb.DownloadString("https://www.rolimons.com/itemapi/itemdetails"));
                Console.WriteLine(dictObj.Keys);
            }
         }
```

Error its outputting:

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'items', line 1, position 43
```

Im trying to output all of the json names.

Comment: Start by saving the JSON string in a variable and ensuring it matches a `Dictionary<string, string>`. Probably not, according to the error.

Comment: try wb.DownloadString("https://www.rolimons.com/itemapi/itemdetails") with the actual string and see if the error persist.

Answer (score 0):

item's field value is not a string but an array. Check the image below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your output has 3 fields and 3rd one is a List which again has a list as a value. So to Deserialize it, you need one class with your fields. Then use JObject and JToken to get actual values.
Below link has similar answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246724/5829426