# How read the raw JSON string value part as mentioned below

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Input string i have is:

```
{"data": "{
\"AckNo\":\"112110045659900\",
\"AckDt\":\"2021-01-24 01:14:00\",
\"Irn\":\"543e3dcd9ecd215ffdb75496a72d5272922b1a929f6c8f728298a9db910c8c5b\"}"}
```

I want read the data of `AckNo`, `AckDt`, `Irn`.

How to separate or split the above value part of the `data` node.

Comment: If you don’t want to deserialize to custom class, you can use Newtonsoft.JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSON inside another JSON... Using [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
var des = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);

// The inner data
string data = (string)des["data"];

// From string to object
var desInner = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

// The properties you want
string ackNo = (string)desInner["AckNo"];
DateTime ackDt = (DateTime)desInner["AckDt"];
string irn = (string)desInner["Irn"];
```

If `ackDt` is optional you could:

```
var ackDt = (DateTime?)desInner["AckDt"];
```

And if you want `ackNo` to be a number:

```
long ackNo = (long)desInner["AckNo"];
```

or (if it is optional):

```
long? ackNo = (long?)desInner["AckNo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following thread. It would help you.

You just need to create class which could represent the json string and follow.

[How to Convert JSON object to Custom C# object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246694/how-to-convert-json-object-to-custom-c-sharp-object)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a class structure that matches your json.

```
public class MyData
{
    public Details Data { get; set; }
}
public class Details
{
    public string AckNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime AckDt { get; set; }
    public string Irn { get; set; }
}
```

Then use `JsonConvert` to deserialize it.
Install package `NewtonSoft.Json` to use `JsonConvert`.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(yourInputString);
var ackNo = result.Data.AckNo;
var ackDt = result.Data.AckDt;
var irn = result.Data.Irn;
```