# Pass a javascript array to a c# method

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays

I have an array that is created in javascript based upon checked items. Once this array gets created (integer array), how can I pass this to c#? Would it be easier to make a hidden text box and just add all the items in a string and just split that string up within c#? For example, if the checkboxes for rows 1,3,7 and clicked, my array is { 1,3,7 }. Again, would it be easier to have a hidden textbox that gets the string "1,3,7" and I just get the string from the text box?

Comment: There is a function to decode JSON in C#, isn't it? Array is a JSON too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334479/json-decoding-in-c

Answer (score 2):

I would pass the array to your C# code behind using an ajax post to a web method.

Answer (score 2):

That is a perfectly acceptable way to pass a JS array to your codebehind file.

Just make sure you have an input control like a hidden field marked with the runat="server" and set the value of the control to the result of a .join(',') of your JS array. You can probably do this with the javascript function that created the array in the first place.

```
 var hiddenField = $get("<%= hdnFieldControl.ClientID %>");
 hiddenField.value = jsArray.join(',');
```

On the server you would then split the string value of the control again to reclaim your array.

```
var serverSideArray = hdnFieldControl.value.Split(new char[0]{',');
```

One note about this method, it will result in an array of strings. If you really want an array of int's you could convert it as another step:

```
int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(serverSideArray, int.Parse);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give each checkbox a 'name' property with the same value, you will receive a comma-separated list:

```
<input type-"checkbox" name="whatever" value="1" />
<input type-"checkbox" name="whatever" value="3" />
<input type-"checkbox" name="whatever" value="7" />
```

Then in your code:

```
string values = Request.Form["whatever"]
```